# Adding Segment (Contains: Page) reduces figures for other Segments

Tags: google-analytics

I am digging into why a Segment is showing numbers that are so low.

At our organisation we have permanent iPads set up which have their own landing page on our website (index.html?cafe=1).*

If I have no Segments applied (which defaults to All Users) go to Behaviour > Site Content > All Pages and apply a page filter for `index.html\?cafe=1` it shows pageviews of over 27,000.

[image: Page filtered by one specific URL]

Then if I add a Segment which has an Advanced Condition of Sessions Include: Page contains `/index.html?cafe=1` the numbers for both 'All Users' Segment and the constrained Segment are 515 pageviews:

[image]

Why does the data for 'All Users' drop with the presence of a comparison Segment?

I also had expected the Segment to show a higher number of pageviews (when the page filter was removed), as my understanding was it would show all sessions where there was any matching pageview, including any subsequent pageviews.  Removing the filter from the page report turns up only 811 Page Views for my Segment.

**I know there are other GA methods to utilise here, but I'm looking at historical data*